# apple imac 2008 BootCamp

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, bootcamp, windows

i have a 2011 imac downstairs in my house and i created a usb windows 7 install on that and when i plug it in it notices it as an install disk however when i plug it into my imac 2008 and click insall windows 7 this comes up

The installer disc could not be found.
 Insert your Windows installer disc and wait a few seconds for the disc to be recognized.

i do not know what to do as it is noticed on my other imac it noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase your question:

You ran `Boot Camp Assistant` on a 2011 iMac to create a Windows 7 install disk on a USB drive using an existing Windows 7 install CD.

This worked when installing Windows 7 into the Boot Camp partition on **that** iMac but it is not recognised when attempting to do the same on an older iMac.

Is that right?

If so your problem may well be that some of the drivers required by the older Mac are not on the USB drive. Try creating the install USB using Boot Camp on the older Mac and it should work fine.

Comment: When I try to create it on the older iMac it doesn't give me the option to create a windows 7 install disk I read about changing the info.plist file but bootcamp assistant don't open